# Seaborn histplot stacked bar not stacking as expected in Python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, histogram

I have a `histplot` that is not doing what I am expecting, and I'm unsure why. In my `histplot`, I want a stacked chart comparing wins by `black_first_move`, but instead of stacked bars, I'm getting the chart in the image below (and the palette's not being applied). Can anyone provide guidance on how to correctly stack this?

```
color=['white', 'lightgrey', 'black']
black_fmr_summary_low.head(2)

sns.histplot(
    data=black_fmr_summary_low, multiple="stack",
    x="black_first_move", y="wins", hue="winner",
    palette=color) # color = ['black', 'white', 'gray'] but is not applying
plt.show()
```

[image: Image of Jupyter Notebook]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that histograms aggregate uncounted data, but you've already counted the `wins`.

Generally bar plots make more sense for counted data, but it seems that the simplest way to make a [stacked bar chart in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59038979/13138364) is via [`histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) with the `weights` param:

> **`weights`** (vector or key in data): If provided, weight the contribution of the corresponding data points towards the count in each bin by these factors.

```
sns.histplot(
    data=df,
    multiple="stack",
    x="black_first_move",
    weights="wins",  # not y="wins"
    hue="winner",
    palette=color)
```

Output with some minimal random data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my stacking! Is there a way to specify I want a percent stacked chart though? I wasn't able to find anything in the histplot references, but I'd imagine there must be a way... or do I need to do this manually via the dataframe, and then create the chart?

Comment: For reference, I've tried adding in stat="percent" but that does not change the bars to be full-length (I want percent by column, not percent by total graph).

Comment: @Justin123 Unfortunately I don't know how to do that in seaborn. I think the only way is to calculate it manually in the dataframe and use pandas `...plot.bar(stacked=True)`

Comment: I guess that becomes a different problem, maybe something like [How to plot stacked & normalized histograms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43074199/13138364) or [How do I make pandas catagorical stacked bar chart scale to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56251848/13138364)